# SAS proc mixed Degree of freedom error

Tags: sas, mixed-models, random-effects

I have a dataset in this format:

[image]

Factor A is a between subject factor (with 2 levels - High and Low).
Factor B is a within subject factor (with 3 levels - High , Moderate and Low).

I want to run a mixed model with nested random effects factor.

The code that I am using is:

```
proc mixed data=data.mydata;
class FactorA FactorB;
model DV = FactorA|FactorB;
random FactorB(FactorA) FactorB*FactorA(FactorA);
lsmeans FactorA|FactorB;
run;
```

The log states: **Estimated G matrix is not positive definite.**
I also do not get any of the p-values (only a '.' is displayed).

Furthermore in the output tables, I see that DF = 0. I have a hunch that this is what is symptomatic of the error. But I have been unable to figure out why this is happening. Any leads will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to SAS documentation:

> The Estimated G matrix not positive definite message usually indicates that one or more variance components on the RANDOM statement is/are estimated to be zero and could/should be removed from the model.

I would suggest you start with a simpler random statement, perhaps just with intercept and gradually add effects (first main before considering interactions).

As for the degree of freedom, knowing that the default `ddfm` for a model with random statement is `contain` which requires large sample size, I would suggest you try other methods like `KR` or `SAT`.

Once your models are yielding results you can then go ahead and modify the model according to your preferences based on the data you have.